# SQL UPDATE: integer divided by count of a specified value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

SQL Server 2008:

Supposing a table of customers, and a column called "Shipping_State".  I want to split the $10,000 spent on shipping costs equally amongst all customers who have Shipping_State = Ohio value, so if there's 2 in Ohio 1 month, it'll be 5,000 a piece, if there's 100 the next month, it'll be 100 a piece. 
I have a blank column in the table named Cost for that calculated value. Cost is a decimal(18,4) data type.  I'd like to be able to use the query for any data types (usually nchar).

How would I accomplish this?  My incorrect code in SQL Server Mgmt Studio returns the message:

> Msg 157, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 An aggregate may not appear in the
>   set list of an UPDATE statement.

```
UPDATE CustomerTable
SET Cost = (10000 / COUNT(CustomerTable.Shipping_State))
WHERE CustomerTable.Shipping_State = 'Ohio';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use nested `SELECT`.

```
UPDATE CustomerTable
SET Cost = (SELECT 10000.0 / count(*)
            FROM CustomerTable
            WHERE CustomerTable.Shipping_state = 'Ohio')
WHERE CustomerTable.Shipping_State = 'Ohio';
```

Comment: This was almost perfect; in my table I have 73 values that fit the criteria, which would be 10000/73 = 136.9863.  Cost is a decimal(18,4) column, but it returned all values as 136.0000.  Any ideas how to get the values down to the decimal?

Comment: Fixed. I hope it's acceptable to use floating point arithmetic.

Comment: I think so!  It did what I wanted, so I have no complaints, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to do a sub-query to get the count, and then update based on this value, something like this should work:

```
UPDATE CustomerTable
SET Cost = (10000 / CTCount.Shipping_State_Count)
FROM CustomerTable CT 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Shipping_State, COUNT(Shipping_State) AS Shipping_State_Count
    FROM CustomerTable 
    GROUP BY Shipping_State) CTCount ON
    CT.Shipping_State = CTCount.Shipping_State
WHERE CT.Shipping_State = 'Ohio';
```

Comment: This one said: Cannot call methods on nchar. Is there a way to adjust for that data type?  (my analogy probably wasn't perfect as my "shipping_state" is actually numerical values in my actual data set. )

Comment: Is the cost column nchar?  Which column is it referring to, does the error message give you any indication?

Comment: cost column is decimal(18,4).  I'll update my post for more info. Full error msg: Msg 258, Level 15, State 1, Line 2 / Cannot call methods on nchar.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server offers two things that really help with this type of query.  The first is updatable CTEs and the second are window functions.

```
with toupdate as (
      select ct.*, count(*) over (partition by ct.Shipping_State) as cnt
      from CustomerTable
      where ct.Shipping_State = 'Ohio'
     )
update toupdate
    set Cost = cast(10000 as float) / cnt;
```

Note that `10000` is cast to a floating point number.  SQL Server does integer division, and I presume you want integers here (actually, `money` would probably be a better data type).

It is unclear how "month" fits in, but this might be closer to what you are looking for:

```
with toupdate as (
      select ct.*, count(*) over (partition by ct.Shipping_State, month(ct.Shipping_Date) as cnt
      from CustomerTable
      where ct.Shipping_State = 'Ohio'
     )
update toupdate
    set Cost = cast(10000 as float) / cnt;
```

Note the change to the `partition by` clause.

Comment: Month over month data is on hold until I figure out what I'm doing, but I'll file this away as I'll end up using it later.  Appreciate the look.