# SQL UPDATE: integer divided by Count Distinct values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is an addendum to this question I asked regarding dividing an integer by the count of a specified value: 
[SQL UPDATE: integer divided by count of a specified value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23764986/sql-update-integer-divided-by-count-of-a-specified-value)

I'm trying to adjust that to divide an integer based on the count of distinct values.

Example: $10,000 of shipping costs for each distinct occurrence in `Shipping_State` will be divided equally amongst the number of records in that distinct occurrence. That value will go in the Column 'Cost'.

So for the 5 records that say Ohio, cost is 2000.0000 each, 10 records for Texas will return 1000.0000 each, 42 records for California, 238.0952 each, etc.

- Table: `CustomerTable`
- Columns: `Shipping_State nchar, Cost decimal(18,4)`

I made a few efforts in vain, here's one attempt:

```
UPDATE CustomerTable
SET Cost = (SELECT 10000.00 / count(*)
            FROM CustomerTable
            WHERE CustomerTable.Shipping_state = COUNT(DISTINCT CustomerTable.Shipping_State)
WHERE CustomerTable.Shipping_State = COUNT(DISTINCT CustomerTable.Shipping_State;
```

I get this error:

> Msg 147, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
>   An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is 
>   in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, 
>   and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is what you are looking for:

```
UPDATE CustomerTable
    SET Cost = (SELECT 10000.00 / count(*)
                FROM CustomerTable ct2
                WHERE CustomerTable.Shipping_state = ct2.Shipping_State
               );
```

I think you are better off with my solution to your previous question, but without the `where`:

```
with toupdate as (
      select ct.*, count(*) over (partition by ct.Shipping_State, month(ct.Shipping_Date)) as cnt
      from CustomerTable
     )
update toupdate
    set Cost = cast(10000 as float) / cnt;
```

Edit:

If you don't want the date, just remove it from the `partition by` clause:

```
with toupdate as (
      select ct.*, count(*) over (partition by ct.Shipping_State) as cnt
      from CustomerTable
     )
update toupdate
    set Cost = cast(10000 as float) / cnt;
```

Comment: for the uninitiated such as myself, what's the benefit of the latter; is there a boost in efficiency, or is the syntax just more logically defined?

Comment: @coburne . . . (1) It should provide a performance gain because it doesn't have to do that actual counting multiple times (caveat:  as with all things performance, it is worth testing); (2) it is a powerful syntax that is easier to understand and maintain, for those who understand SQL.

Comment: I'm trying your method now.  The top one is saying: Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Divide by zero error encountered

Comment: @coburne . . . This is hard to imagine with the query as written.  The `count(*)` will count matching rows and the `where` guarantees at least one matching row because it is to the same table.  Perhaps it could happen with some execution paths if `Shipping_State` were `NULL`.

Comment: You're right, there are a handful of NULL values in Shipping_State now that I look through it.

Comment: @coburne . . . (3) it handles NULL values.

Comment: if I gave you some candy would you tell me how to do yours w/o a date field in the table?

Comment: nevermind, I got your 1st method working using some NULLIF shenanigans.  Cheers!